# Wingpanel locale styling

Tags: updates, wingpanel

After the last update of the wingpanel yesterday the locale became a **white colored text over a white background**, and I don't find it "super sexy" like this. Is it possible to style it somehow, for example to keep the white text but to completely remove (make it transparent) the background?

Comment: Plus one. This white-on-white nonsense can't possibly be a conscious decision made by the design team. It's clearly a bug! Would you please report this to the devs?

Comment: Yes, probably you are right. I did that - https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues/265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution :)

1. As admin, open `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css` file.
2. Find the lines:

`.composited-indicator .keyboard {
    background-color: #fff;`

3. Change the `background-color` parameter to whatever you want (and then save and reboot). 
   Blue, for example, is `#0099ff`:

[image: keyboard indicator]

Comment: it is not necessary to reboot, if you have elementary-tweaks just change the theme to another one, and return to elementary ) . What I recommend is to make `background-color:transparent` also `box-shadow:none` or just comment `/* box-shadow.... */` the box-shadow block. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably it is no longer valid, because after the last update it is again white background, with black text.. It is ok for now no matter that I prefer only text without background, but I want to know how do you found the css class used in the app.css? Some documentation somewhere?

Comment: On my PC (with all stock updates) keyboard indicator stays blue until now. Concerning its css property: I found it by myself accidentally, when searching for the way to shorten the distance between wingpanel icons. Here's the thread: https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1#issuecomment-412634500

Comment: Hmm.. I have changed in all the themes I use (including the default elementary theme you mention in your answer) the same property and it was fine until today, after a System Settings update. Now all the themes has a white background with black color, also changing the padding you mention above does not work... I believe that after this update the classes are changed.

Comment: As mentioned in the quoted tread, icon padding property has ceased to work in wingpanel v2.2.6. (It doesn't work on my system either.)