# How to change text style of the top panel and app menu

Tags: wingpanel, pantheon, gala

After setting a new theme in elementary-tweaks I'm now looking for a .css or configuration file to change the style of the text in the top panel and app menu to fit the style of the theme.
More precisely I would like it not to be bold, and even change the font, matching the title bar of the windows.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: See https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/wingpanel-locale-styling

Comment: I can't find the line to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install elementary tweaks. And you can visit the previous question similar like these in [Here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/is-elementary-tweaks-still-working-on-hera)

Comment: Unfortunately, elementary-tweaks doesn’t have a specific setting for the top panel. Also I have checked a lot of previous posts, but things are changed with gala, and I can't find the proper solution. Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: @Nicco or you can install gnome tweaks. I used that tool. 

sudo apt install gnome-tweaks

Comment: I tried, also I spent a lot of time with gnome-shell-extensions before realising that elementary uses pantheon haha

Comment: Themes are responsible for this in Elementary OS. So you must edit a theme in /usr/share/themes

Answer (score 0):

Themes are responsible for this in Elementary OS. So you must edit a theme in /usr/share/themes.